# Streamline Process across SKU Groups - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a total of 12 different SKU groups (and thus dataframes). I need to find the outliers within each group and then create a new dataframe showing only the outliers from the original data frame.Below is the steps and processes that I have built out and created but for only 1 sku group.

```py
#Data frames created from masterData

SHAPEWEAR_df = grouped_skus.get_group('SHAPEWEAR')

LEGGINGS_df = grouped_skus.get_group('LEGGINGS')

ACTIVEWEAR_df = grouped_skus.get_group('ACTIVEWEAR')

 #etc...

#LEGGINGS_df

LEGGINGS_outliers = find_outliers_IQR(LEGGINGS_df['VOLUME'])
index_hos = LEGGINGS_outliers.index.tolist()


index_hos = LEGGINGS_outliers.index.tolist()
ints = []
for element in index_hos:
    ints.append(int(element))
#print(ints)

outliers_LEGGINGS_df = LEGGINGS_df.loc[ints]

LEGGINGS_outliers.count()
```

Can i put all the remaining 11 data frames into a list and have these requirements run? I can eventually get to the answer that I want but dont wish to create another df if a new SKU group is created down the road.

Attached is a picture of the manual process i am currently working towards.

[Manual Process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwFVG.png)

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: The code from the image is attached here as code. Everything below #Leggings_Df is the code from the workbook/image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.